# React Redux this.props.getClasses is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to pass action with mapDispatchToProps to component,
when i am trying to use getClasses as this.props.getClasses().
I am getting **Failed prop type: The prop `getClasses` is marked as required in `HierarchySelect`, but its value is `undefined`.**
and on 'section' select component is crashing with **TypeError: this.props.getClasses is not a function**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const { Fragment } = React;
export class HierarchySelect extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sections: [],
      section: '--',
    };
  }

  handleChange (value, type, error) {
    switch (type) {
      case 'section':
        this.setState({
          section: value
        });
        this.props.getClasses({ type: '', data: '' });
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <select id="lang" className="section" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, 'section')} value={this.state.section}>
          {['--', ...this.state.sections].map(d => <option key={d} value={d}>{d}</option>)}
        </select>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

HierarchySelect.propTypes = {
  deptHierarchy: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  createHierarchy: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  getClasses: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  user: state.getUser
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

  getClasses: (data) => {
    dispatch(data);
  }

});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HierarchySelect);
```

Comment: Are you passing the getClasses function as params from parent to child component ?

Comment: here the child component is HierarchySelect right ?

Comment: @Prabhu getClasses function should be passed from connect function as props.

Answer (score 1):

In mapDispatchToProps you are not returning the dispatch in getClasses. You need to write it like

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getClasses: (data) => {
       return dispatch(data);
    }
});
```

or

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getClasses: (data) => dispatch(data);
});
```

Also you need to import the connected component which is the default export in your case

```
import HierarchySelect  from './hierarchy-dropdowns';
```

Comment: i have tried this also. hierarchy-dropdowns.jsx:42 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getClasses is not a function

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getClasses: data => dispatch(data)
});

Comment: how are you importing HierarchySelect

Comment: import { HierarchySelect } from './hierarchy-dropdowns';

file name is hierarchy-dropdowns

Comment: you need to import the connected component  which is the default export `import  HierarchySelect  from './hierarchy-dropdowns';`

Comment: Great thanks it worked, I just had to make eslint understand i am doing right. 
import HierarchySelect from './hierarchy-dropdowns'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-named-as-default
Any other way that does not require to change eslint config.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

`handleChange` is not binded to component `this` instance.So, you getting `props` as undefined.

Define `handleChange` with

[`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which do `lexical` `this` binding.

```
handleChange = (value, type, error) =>{
            this.props.getClasses();
        }
      }
```

OR

In constructor do `this` binding with `bind`:

```
constructor(){

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: it is binded, just that the binding is done inline `onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, 'section')}`